# How to give greater than or equal to in Search API

Tags: search, search-results, search-api

```
/sites/my/_api/search/query?querytext=%27(ContentTypeId:0x01489534544341EDD* AND ListId:C694N7-C900-48BE-V1E3-5094087615F2 AND FYOWSNMBR>=2000) %27&rowlimit=30&TrimDuplicates=true&selectproperties=%27ListItemID,Title,FYOWSNMBR%27
```

The above url is the one i use for Search API.

If I use FYOWSNMBR=2000 ,I will get result

But If I use FYOWSNMBR>=2000,I get an error message:" We didn't understand your search terms. Make sure they're using proper syntax."
Also I tried different combinations

Please provide me a suitable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Troubleshooting Tip:**

1. **>=** is supported only for **DateTime, Integer, Decimal, Double** but **=** is supported for **Text** also. Make sure the FYOWSNMBR managed property is not of type Text and belongs to one of above mentioned type.
2. Include a space between property and **>=**. In many cases I have faced that the absence of space causing wrong syntax error
   eg: FYOWSNMBR >=2000

Comment: FYOWSNMBR  is a number.So it should be also possible right?

Comment: Try to add space between FYOWSNMBR  & >=

Comment: I didnt change the data type in search schema.Now I changed it and is working now
Thank you :)